# Failed to detect the name of this notebook, you can set it manually with the WANDB_NOTEBOOK_NAME env

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, wandb

In Visual Studio Code, first I encounted issues logging into wandb. I’ve tried specifying the entity as ‘myusername’, but it hasn’t resolved the problem. I’ve also confirmed that I’m using the latest version of wandb. My project folder is located on the Desktop.

```
os.environ["WANDB_API_KEY"] = 'API_KEY'

!wandb login API_KEY
/Users/myname/.netrc

machine api.wandb.ai
  login user
  password API_KEY
```

when I run wandb.init I get this error

```
Changes to your `wandb` environment variables will be ignored because your `wandb` session has already started. For more information on how to modify your settings with `wandb.init()` arguments, please refer to [the W&B docs](https://wandb.me/wandb-init).
wandb: ERROR Error while calling W&B API: user is not logged in (<Response [401]>)
```

Then I decided to run it on terminal insisted of jupyter notebook cell but I got this error

```
Failed to detect the name of this notebook, you can set it manually with the WANDB_NOTEBOOK_NAME environment variable to enable code saving.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following steps to solve it:

1. Check your API.
2. Check your `.netrc` File. Make sure this file contains the correct login and password.
3. Set the `WANDB_API_KEY` environment variable.
4. Install the latest version of `Wandb` by command `pip install --upgrade wandb`.